# Android emulator and nested virtualization

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, hyper-v

I have a problem. I use hyper-v virtual machine to isolate development process. I use windows 10 on virtual machine. But I can't install hypervisor on my virtual machine. How I can debug xamarin.forms application without hyper-v?

Thanks.

> **QUICK ANSWER**: YES. It isn't possible. Nesting hyper-v works.

1. VM should not have dynamic RAM. Should be static.
2. You should enable nested virtualization by the following command in Powershell:

Set-VMProcessor -VMName  -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true

See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

Answer (score 1):

Everything will work:

1. You should enable nested virtualization by the following command in Powershell: `Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`
2. You must enable the ***hyper-v*** component on the virtual machine
3. Processor must be ***Intel***

P.S.
This will only work on a Windows 10 virtual machine or higher.
This will not work on a windows server virtual machine.
This is how I implemented several virtual machines with Windows 10 and Android Studio on a Windows server...

Comment: Do you know why it doesn’t work on Windows Server? According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/enable-nested-virtualization, this should be supported with "any Windows supported guest operating system."

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that can be used on Windows 10.

1. **Shutdown or switch off** your virtual machine.
2. **Open powershell** with administrator rights.
3. Apply

> Set-VMProcessor -VMName "" -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true

where "VMName" name of VM.
4. It enables nested hyper-v.

PS> It's preview feature. That can work unstable. Windows 10 with the same build should be installed on host and VM. No dynamic memory, save/restore feature are supported. **it's PREVIEW feature.** Please, read more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**UPDATE**

I'm able to install hypervisor on virtual machine. But I'm not able to run nested virtual machine with android image by Visual Studio Emulator for Android. Eventlog of hypervisor says:

> 'VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone.a.ripenko' was reset
>   because an unrecoverable error occurred on a virtual processor that
>   caused a triple fault. This error might have been caused by a problem
>   in the hypervisor. If the problem persists, contact Product Support.
>   (Virtual machine ID )

Seems that nesting hyper-v is raw and it doesn't work as expected yet.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem but nested virtualization is possible. I set up an environment with this configuration: **Physical machine (WinServer2016)** -> **VM (WinServer2016)** -> **VS Emulator for Android** and it worked as expected.