# Unable to run Android Emulator on Nested Virtualization

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I managed to setup a Hyper-V VM (Guest) which have Nested Virtualization enable, from similar steps from here: [Android emulator and nested virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484893/android-emulator-and-nested-virtualization)

Specs I have is,

```
Host VM: Windows 10 OS Build 21277.1000
Guest VM: Windows 10 20H2 OS Build 19042.630
```

Running on AMD Ryzen 5 3550H processor.

After installing Android Studio and installed the *gvm-windows_v1_7_0.zip* driver, creating a Android device, running it it shows a popup notification indicating that is has detected nested virtualization, I just hit okay, then press the emulator power on button.

It started very slow, barely getting out of the boot screen, so I checked the task manager, and found that it is running *qemu-system-i386.exe*

What have I missed that made the emulator run on virtualized mode instead of running in emulation mode which barely can boot?